# Spring Boot Main and JavaFX

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, spring-boot

I have Java Application that changes a game board (2D). Now I want to have a JavaFx GUI to visualize the board.

Main:

```
package example;

import example.common.MyService;
import example.gui.GUI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"example"})
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        GUI.launchApp(GUI.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("gameloop or something");
        System.out.println(myService.getSomething());
    }

}
```

AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport:

```
package example.gui;


import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public abstract class AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport extends Application {

    private static String[] savedArgs;
    static ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        super.init();
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(getClass(), savedArgs);
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        applicationContext.close();
    }

    public static void launchApp(Class<? extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport> appClass, String[] args) {
        AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.savedArgs = args;
        Application.launch(appClass, args);
    }

}
```

GUI:

```
package example.gui;

import example.common.MyService;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GUI extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        if (null == myService) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Service was not injected properly");
        }

        primaryStage.setTitle("Spring with JavaFX");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello World with " + myService.getSomething()));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

MyService:

```
package example.common;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyService {
    public int getSomething() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Most JavaFx spring boot integrations are like the shown above: They prescribe the GUI as entry point for the application. If I run this example two individual applications are booted (obviously. Because there are two SpringApplication.run calls). If you want a Standalone GUI this is fine but for my usecase it is not.

What I really want is one boot and that they share the same context. How to archive this? I would be grateful if somebody could lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want 2 applications, where first is game server and the second is UI for this, or you just want to pass your application context to GUI?

Comment: GUI and App should run in parallel and they should have the same  application context so that I can inject the same service into both or later for sharing the same board of my game. The problem currently is that I have two SpringApplication.run calls and don't know how to share the same application context.

Comment: What means in parallel? Can App be running without GUI and GUI without App?

Comment: In parallel means that the GUI runs in the JavaFx Thread and the Main in another thread. The GUI can't run without the board that is modified in the App. So the GUI has a clear dependency on the App. And the App should be able to run without the GUI (that's the main reason I need to have the App as entry-point).

Comment: How much clients(GUI) can be for this app?

Comment: There is only one GUI and one App. No networking, server-client or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need follow fix for your `AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public abstract class AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport extends Application {

static ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    super.init();
    applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    super.stop();
    applicationContext.close();
}

public static void launchApp(Class<? extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport> appClass, ConfigurableApplicationContext context, String[] args) {
    applicationContext = context;
    Application.launch(appClass, args);
}

}
```

So, for your example thats enough. You just pass context created before.

But at first, I don't think that you need make your application as component of context - I don't know how can you use it. At second, I think you will use `fxml` for your UI, and for this purposes you can use `FxmlLoader`. This loader has term `Controller` which means that this `Controller` will initialize all components (in terms of JavaFx) in this class. So, for dependency injection for this `Controllers` you can use method `FxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);`. But it will work only for this `Controller`'s, not for some views or panels

Comment: Does anyone know why this answer got minus?