# using javafx client with spring boot and spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, javafx, spring-security

I'm going to create a javafx client and  http server using spring boot that includes authentication.

The server is planning to use spring security for login and appache httpClient for clients.

Can I create a login service from this structure?

Or should I choose a different method?

I understand Spring security authenticates using cookie and session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a hybrid application using `JavaFX` and `Spring-Boot`. And of course, you can use `Spring Security` as well. I recommend you to use `maven` project to package your hybrid-application.

> Can I create a login service from this structure?

Yes, you can!

> Or should I choose a different method?

As you can use `spring-security` for your login service, you may not need other methods but you can use a lot of `authentication-authorization` libraries.

> **Why Apache-HttpClient?**

It seems you are planning to use `Apache-HttpClient` to bind your JavaFX and Spring-Boot services. Actually you can use your login service in your JavaFX application without exposing the service as a Restful Service. You can use spring's *Dependency Injection* to wire your service in your JavaFX controller class. ex:

```
@Autowired
private LoginService loginService;
```

If you are comfortable with spring applications you can also use functionalities that spring provides such as `Spring Data JPA`, etc.

> **SpringBoot + JavaFX Application**

Here is a simple example of hybrid application,

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApp extends Application {

    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = springBootApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springBootApplicationContext() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApp.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().stream().toArray(String[]::new);
        return builder.run(args);
    }

}
```

It's not possible to define a `boilerplate` of application here but the above code does the tricks to start the application.

> P.S.: You can check this [JavaFXSpringBootApp](https://github.com/RamAlapure/JavaFXSpringBootApp) boilerplate to review the needed ideas.