# Issue with 2 main Methods Java And JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, program-entry-point

I have currently 2 classes, both with main methods, inside one project. The first class looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public void handle(String s) {...}

}
```

and the other one is a simple JavaFX starting class:

```
public class MainMenue extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

My plan is to start the javafx App to have some buttons and all the fxml feature, and I would like to start the other application with a button event. That already works fine. BUT I have to use some methods from the normal Java application from the JavaFX app. To be more specific, there is a handle method which takes String as parameter, and I would like to write the String in a `Textfield` in JavaFX and by clicking a Button, the method "handle" from the normal Java application should get done.

I couldn't find any solution to solve this. Making the class Application extends Application AND implementing this interface isn't working fine.

Do you have any solutions or other ways to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Combine the two, and start the SpringBoot application context in the JavaFX `Application`'s `init()` method. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198935/using-javafx-client-with-spring-boot-and-spring-security)

Comment: Thank you very Much! I did so and there are no Errors, but the JavaFX GUI isn't loading. The normal application is a commandLineRunner, so I think java likes to wait for the execution of this task. When I put the line "springContext = springBootApplicationContext();" from init() into start() after loading the GUI, the gui window appears but is only loading not interactable. Is there a way to run both application simultaniously? So I can work with the gui and the SprinBootApp will run,too at the same time?